# Put satin on women's panties

Tags: meaning

Was watching Prison Break Season 5 Episode 1 and came across this very sentence at the beginning:

### "What is it with you killers that put the satin on women's panties anyhow?"

What does "put satin on women's panties" mean?

Answer (score 5):

This is funny, I think it's a phrase taken from a Tupac song. Satin is a "sexy" fabric.

"You put the satin on women's panties" in more-boring-speak would be something like "You are the reason women wear sexy underwear."

Comment: wow.. I'm glad I didn't put forward a guess... I thought it meant something extremely vulgar!

Comment: I think it could be taken in a more vulgar way if the audience was so inclined -- like with any good euphemism.

Comment: RIP to the one who put the satin on their panties. Shock G.

Answer (score 0):

The implication may be that a woman gets wet when thinking about a killer. The cotton panties suffused with the juices turn to satin.

Oh, and the sentence needs a comma before "anyhow".